# Solr treats whitespace and other special tags in query like "OR"

Tags: solr, tokenize

I have a text field with the following definition:

```
<fieldType name="myTextField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1"
                        maxGramSize="40"/>

            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Now, i have a field that contains this text:
"Hi this is a question about solr"

And another field that contains this text:
"aaa solr bbb"

When my query string is "about solr", i'm getting both fields as a result, though i only want the first one because it is the only one that contains all characters (including white space).
This is not only happening with white space, but also with other special chars like ":".
searching for (about solr) with brackets doesn't help.

NOTE: i'm escaping my string before searching it:

```
String s1 = ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(s);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior of Solr. You will need to use **about** AND **solr** to get the behavior you want. The default is OR. If you want to change this behavior you can do it by using q.op parameter as q.op=AND , then **about solr** will be processed as per your expectation. But it is not a good idea to change the OR to AND as OR is generally assumed so it is not a good idea to change it. Instead  change your query to AND.

Standard analyzer breaks your phrases at whitespace and special characters. There is no such list, any non alpha numeric char becomes white space.

Read more about analyzer here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

**Update:** The characters that break for StandardTokenizerFactory are for example &,. ,- etc. So this sentence : "Me & my Dog went for a walk. The dog chased a toy-squirrel." will be analyzed as => Me my Dog went for a walk The dog chased a toy squirrel.

If you want to break only at white space use : WhitespaceTokenizerFactory

**Update :**  The characters that break for WhitespaceTokenizerFactory are white  space and new line . So this sentence : "Me & my Dog went for a walk. The dog chased a toy-squirrel." will be analyzed as => [Me] [&] [my] [Dog] [went] [for] [a] [walk.] [The] [dog] [chased] [a] [toy-squirrel.].

Comment: Can you be more specific? where should i use AND? Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer. Post your query so that i can further update my answer.

Comment: What are the other characters  that break the text to phrases besides whitespace? i didn't found such list

Comment: They obey the Unicode standards, see here http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries

Comment: Thanks! But there's no way to define fieldType somehow such that those characters will be indexed regularly for this field and won't break the text into phrases?

Comment: Yes, that would be using WhitespaceTokenizerFactory in place of your StandardTokenizerFactory as I mentioned in my response.  Also you need to accept answers for original question and not use this as full thread for all issues , that way people in future can refer to these answers and not get confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can use solr phrase query. Your query syntex will look like:

```
String query = "\"about solr\"";
```

Then it would match the field that you require.

Your current query is interpreted like:

```
String query = "about OR solr";
```

So it will match both fields, the reson behind this is for solr query parser default operaor is "OR". Check your schema.xml file it's having following entry:

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

Hope this will clear your doubt.

For more details please refer below links:

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

http://www.solrtutorial.com/schema-xml.html

Comment: Thx. Can I somehow override the defaultOperator for a certain field type? and what are the other "strip chars" besides the white space?

Comment: And i wonder if there's a way to define the field type so that "strip chars" like spaces will be indexed like regular chars

Comment: @axelrod the default operator is applied to all fields so you can not override it for certain fields. I am not sure but I think all non alphanumeric characters are strip chars in this case.

Comment: @axelrod to index all characters you can use "string" field type so your field value is not tokenised in this field type and it indexed as it is.

Comment: But i'm indexing entire text files in this fields. Doesn't String field have a length limit? I also don't need whole field match.

Comment: @axelrod if you don't need whole field match then you should not use string field type. I do not understand why you want to index spaces though you not require whole field match.

Comment: Because I need to implement something like "search whole words only", and a "word" in a document can contain white spaces, commas, dot, etc...

Comment: @axelrod please understand use of tokenizer, here you are using StandardTokenizerFactory at index type as well as for query type which means white spacea are not indexed and when you are searching some word then also it first tokenize your string and then start comparing tokens with index. So the query I mentioned in my answer should solve your problem.